# BeaconTools iOS app : Error : Couldn't fetch registration data (while registering with EID)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon, eddystone

I am currently working on iOS application which includes functionality on Beacons. I used google nearby API's for searching Beacon. While integrating Nearby API i am facing below issues.
I am trying to register Beacon (minewtech Eddystone) through "Beacon Tools" iOS application using Broadcast Profile "EID". But i got error while registering.

Same beacon registration succeed from Android version of "Beacon Tools".
I have followed all steps in    https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/ios/get-started tutorial but unfortunately application don't found any beacon even if beacons are          registered(registered from android app) on google beacon dashboard.

I have downloaded sample application from  googlesamples/ios-nearby and run it, but in this app also registered beacon was't detected. Where as in Android app it works fine.

I have created APP_Key from console project and used it while creating GNSMessageManager object.

Let me know if any additional setup require for iOS.
Please Find attached screenshot for reference.

[Reference Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMFSu.png)